# How to make a table of the frequency of a number multiplied by the number raised to 3 in R

Tags: r, frequency

Having the following list, I would like the result of the frequency to be multiplied by its index value raised to 3. How could I do it?

```
data<-c(1,1,2,2,3,34,65,78,65,3)

table(data)

data

 1  2  3 34 65 78 

 2  2  2 1  2  1
```

Expected:

```
 1  2  3 34 65 78 

 2  8*2  27*2 39304*1  274625*2  474552*1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
with(rle(sort(data)), lengths*values^3)
#[1]      2     16     54  39304 549250 474552
```

OR

```
x = table(data)
x*as.numeric(names(x))^3
#data
#1      2      3     34     65     78 
#2     16     54  39304 549250 474552
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider `tapply`:

```
res <- tapply(data, data, function(x) (x[1]^3) * length(x))

#1      2      3     34     65     78 
#2     16     54  39304 549250 474552
```

Answer (score 0):

Note as beautiful as the other answers but a multi-step solution.

Data:

```
data<-c(1,1,2,2,3,34,65,78,65,3)
data <- as.data.frame(table(data))
```

Solve the problem:

```
data$data <- as.numeric(as.character(data$data))
data$powers <- data$data**3
data$final <- data$Freq * data$powers
```

Result:

```
  data Freq powers  final
1    1    2      1      2
2    2    2      8     16
3    3    2     27     54
4   34    1  39304  39304
5   65    2 274625 549250
6   78    1 474552 474552
```